# Magento 2 - Move Block Not Working

Tags: magento2, blocks, xml, page-layouts

I've created a `faqs.xml` for a bespoke page template and this is my code:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="faqs.content" as="faqs_content" label="FAQs Content" after="page.top"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer pd-footer"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="hero-title-content" template="Magento_Theme::html/hero-title-content.phtml" after="usps"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="breadcrumbs" destination="hero-title-content" />
    <move element="page.main.title" destination="hero-title-content" />
    <referenceContainer name="faqs.content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="faqs" template="Magento_Theme::html/faqs.phtml" after="-" />
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="call-to-actions" template="Magento_Theme::html/call-to-actions.phtml" after="-" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

I am trying to move the breadcrumbs and page title into the hero-title-content block however the above doesn't seem to work?

Can anyone please advise why this isn't working?

**EDIT**:

Managed to resolve the breadcrumbs not moving, this was due to another move reference in the `default.xml`. Unsure about the page title as I haven't move this in my `default.xml`

Comment: I think move is not supported in page layout

Answer (score 0):

Well basically you need to make sure that nothing else moves that element or make sure that your module is loaded last.